# Maintaining order for Cadence workflow signals

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Say I have a workflow that receives signal *1* at `T-0` and signal *2* at `T+1`. The workflow is then executed at T+2. When the workflow runs, am I guaranteed that it will receive signal 1 before signal 2? Put another say, does Cadence maintain the order of incoming signals to a workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cadence/Temporal guarantees that signals are delivered in the same order they were received by a workflow execution.

As signals are recorded in a workflow event history and the history is fully consistent providing such guarantee is pretty straightforward.